# What is the connection between adjacency matrix and topological measures

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, algebraic-graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

What are the connections we can draw from a graph's adjacency matrix and topological measures that can be defined on the network induced by the graph? For example can we detect "holes" in a sensor network based on adjacency matrix akin to topological methods in this paper:

[https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/ipsn2005.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eghrist/preprints/ipsn2005.pdf)

It seems the adjacency matrix should contain information for many of the topological measures on a network/graph. Any references or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect holes using much less.

If $G$ is a **connected** undirected graph, the number of holes (alternatively, the $\mathbb Z$-rank of the first homology group of $G$ considered as a CW-complex)  is just $ |E|- |V| + 1$.

You technically can get both $|V|$ and $|E|$ as the number of rows and half the sum of all entries of the adjacency matrix respectively.

Comment: Thank you Arkady. Fantastic. Where is the formal theory on connection between adjacency matrix and topological quantities discussed? Finding holes was a concrete example I had, but if one needs to study others, is this is a sub-topic of topology and graph theory? Where does one find other useful connections like the one you just pointed out - again very helpful!

Comment: What other topological quantities are you interested in? In the setting we are in, topologically things are quite simple. Let’s set $r= |E|-|V|+1$. The homology (and  cohomology) are non-zero in only degrees $0$ and $1$. The first homotopy group is the free group on the same number of generators and in fact the entire graph contracts to the wedge on  $r$ circles. There’s not a whole lot more to say imo.

Comment: "What other topological quantities in the context of graphs" is part of my question since I am not familiar with topology -  what other topological measures/questions  can we pose as computation defined on the adjacency matrices? We can convert/approximate curves and surfaces by discretizing them and converting them into point clouds, ie. nodes on graphs/networks.  I imagine many topological questions and measures can be converted and studied in the context of graphs/networks this way? For example the inscribed square problem (Toeplitz' Conjecture): can adjacency matrix approach help?